# merge contents of two files into one file by bash command

Tags: bash, file-manager, file-mapping

i have two file like blow format and need to marge two file in below format (bash command)

1st row of 1st file + 1st row of 2nd file
2nd row of 1st file + 2nd row of 2nd file

Example :

file1

```
a
b
c
d
```

file2

```
1
2
3
4
```

expected output file

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
```

Comment: Take a look at `man paste`.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: You can simply use `paste -d, file1 file2` or test from the command line in bash with `paste -d, <(printf "%s\n" {a..d}) <(printf "%s\n" {1..4})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

file1_contents=$(<"$file1")
file2_contents=$(<"$file2")

read -ra array1 <<< "$file1_contents"
read -ra array2 <<< "$file2_contents"

final_string=""
for ((i=0; i<"${#array1[@]}"; i++));
do
  final_string+="${array1[i]},${array2[i]} "
done

echo "$final_string"
```

This bash script reads 2 command line arguments, **file1** and **file2**.
Assuming file one has `a b c d` and file2 has `1 2 3 4` as their respective contents, then the script will read the contents of both files and convert the contents into an array using the `read` command. The `-a` option will make the read command convert the **file1_contents** into an array and store the result in the variable **array1**. It will do the same for the contents of the second file.

We then declare a **final_string** variable that will hold the final result. Afterwards we loop through the first array and on each iteration of the loop, we take the current element in the first array and concatenate it to the element at the same position of the second array and this we add to the **final_string**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need the `herestring`, and `command substitution` a simple redirection for reading the file should suffice, e.g. `read -ra array1 < file1; read -ra array2 < file2`

Comment: thanks for the script but i found its only  marge the file line only may be the loop not working